# Program Control: Menu Selectable Subprograms

Tags: c++, oop

Probably a terrible title, I'm not sure how else to phrase it.

I have a final project for an Object Oriented Design class (C++) and the task is to create a casino program with 4 separate games. This is a multiple person project, so I'm looking to use a main file that doesn't need to be edited by each person designing a game class. So, for instance, the 'main' file would contain a menu and prompt for which game you'd like to play. From there, it would use a switch statement to transfer control to that game.

But how would you do that? Does this thinking make sense?

For the SlotMachine.play(), does it make sense to send control inside an object?

```
// Pseudo code

void launchSlotMachine() 
{
    SlotMachine SlotMachine;
    SlotMachine.play();
}

int main() 
{
    int menuSelect = 0;

    cout << "1. Slot Machine << endl;
    // ... 

    cin >> menuSelect;

    switch(menuSelect)
    {
        case 1:
            launchSlotMachine();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way this may belong to the programmers or game developers stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to implement the different games as classes with a run function. You would then give control to them using a switch statement. So yes what you do is the general approach when it comes to similar projects.

Comment: So the run function is just like any other class function, it just contains the sequential execution of the program? I guess that makes sense, but it just seems so foreign to me.

Comment: That's pretty much it. In general games are very modular. You break up the game in rendering, entities, world/collision/resource manager classes and you use them in the running part of the game application class. It makes sense therefore to also make a game/level manager when you need many levels or different games. This class is then called by the main function. In your case you just manage them directly in the main function but that's simply a design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use a Look Up Table or std::map with function pointers.

Your record would be `<game name, pointer to game function>`.  When the record is found containing the game name, you deference the function pointer to activate the name.

There are many examples in StackOverflow of this, search for "C++ dispatch table function pointer".